# How to Show Tab page which is already open

Tags: c#

I got a windows form with Datagridview including Employee information.
when i select say one  Row from dridvie and Click on New Button it loads a new Tabcontrol which Title employee name.
I have implemented so every time user select one row from grid view and click on new Button it adds new tab control with name of Tabpage employee name.
when employee already exists it do now open Particular tab which already Opens thats how i want and it works perfectly fine.
But when i select a row from gridview Employee which Tab is already open and click on new it doesnt open new tab which is ok but if it is already open every time i click new i want to go inside that Tab page How to do it???

Here is my code

```
    private void button_New_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabPage tpEmployee = new TabPage(emp.Vorname);

        tpEmployee.Tag = emp.ID;
        GUI.Ucemp ucempTes = new GUI.UCemp();
        Ucemptest.Employee = emp;
        Ucemptest.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        tpEmployee.Controls.Add(ucempTes);

        Boolean found = false;


        foreach (TabPage tp in tabControl.TabPages)
        {
            if (tp.Tag != null && tp.Tag.Equals(tpEmployee.Tag))
            {
                found = true;
             //Here i want to go inside Tab which is already open
           }
        }

        if (!found)
        {

            this.tabControl.TabPages.Add(tpEmployee);
            tabControl.SelectedTab = tpEmployee;               
        }
     }
```

Comment: Try tabControl.SelectedTab=tp;

Comment: Shouldn't you first search and only create the new tabpage if you didn't find it?